# Why mi i, j, k values are broken? The values they take are not related with the range that they could have

Tags: arrays, c, file, struct

I'm struggling with this code,  its purpose is to accumulate data from a .dat file with structs that have information about marks, age, gender. When I compile it, an error shows that say "segmentation fault", I wrote a printf to show me the value of i, j and k; because I think them are the problem, here is the code and a photo of the failure:
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

struct persona {
    int edad; //EDAD DE 12-65//
    int notas; //NOTAS DE 0-10//
    char sexo; //SEXO 1=MASCULINO Y 2=FEMENINO//
    char exi; //EXI 1=SI 2=NO
};

struct reg {
    int notas;
    int contex;
    int cont;
};

struct reg A[7][6][3];



int grupoedad(struct persona p) {
    if( p.edad < 12) {
        printf("\nexiste un error en la edad");
    } else if(p.edad < 16) {
        return 1;
    } else if(p.edad < 26) {
        return 2;
    } else if(p.edad < 36) {
        return 3;
    } else if(p.edad < 46) {
        return 4;
    } else if(p.edad < 56) {
        return 5;
    } else if(p.edad < 66) {
        return 6;
    }
}

int niveling(struct persona p) {
    if(p.notas < 2) {
        return 1;
    } else if(p.notas < 4) {
        return 2;
    } else if(p.notas < 6) {
        return 3;
    } else if(p.notas < 8) {
        return 4;
    } else if(p.notas <=10) {
        return 5;
    }
}

int femasc(struct persona p) {
    if(p.sexo == 'M'){
        return 1;
    } else if(p.sexo == 'F') {
        return 2;
    }
}

void etario(int j, char grupoed[10]) //ASIGNAMOS LOS RANGOS ETARIOS//
{
    switch(j)
    {
        case(1):
            strcpy(grupoed, "12-15");
            break;
        case(2):
            strcpy(grupoed, "16-25");
            break;
        case(3):
            strcpy(grupoed, "26-35");
            break;
        case(4):
            strcpy(grupoed, "36-45");
            break;
        case(5):
            strcpy(grupoed, "46-55");
            break;
        case(6):
            strcpy(grupoed, "56-65");
        default:
            printf("\nHa ocurrido un error");
    }
}

//void matrizcero(struct reg A[7][6][3], int i, int j, int k) {
   // for (i = 1; i < 7; i++)
   // {
        //for (j = 1; j < 6; j++)
      //  {
        //    for (k = 1; k < 3; k++)
          //  {
            //    A[i][j][k].contex = 0;
              //  A[i][j][k].cont = 0;
                //A[i][j][k].notas = 0;
           // }
       // }
  //  }
// }

int main() {
    struct reg {
    int notas;
    int contex;
    int cont;
    };

    struct reg A[7][6][3];
    struct persona p;   
    int rangomay, rangomen, rangointmay, resmay, resmen, jex, jmay, jmen, NIV, GRUPOET, sexo, cantidadM, califM, cantidadF, califF, grupoetario;
    // matrizcero(A[7][6][3], i, j, k);
    char grupoed[10];
    float prom_m, prom_f;

    FILE *entrada; //ABRO ARCHIVO
    entrada=fopen("datospersonas.txt","ab");
    if (entrada == NULL){
        exit(1);
        printf("\nError al abrir el archivo");
    }
    else {
        printf("\nArchivo abierto exitosamente!");
    }

    while(!(feof(entrada))){
        fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,entrada);
        // void niveling(struct persona p, int i);
        // grupoedad(struct persona p, int j);
        // femasc(struct persona p, int k);
        i = niveling(p);
        j = grupoedad(p);
        k = femasc(p);

        printf("\n%d",i);
        printf("\n%d",j);
        printf("\n%d",k);

        A[i][j][k].notas = A[i][j][k].notas + p.notas;
        A[i][j][k].cont = A[i][j][k].cont;
        if(p.exi = 'S') {
            A[i][j][k].contex = A[i][j][k].contex + 1;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //TOTALIZO HOMBRES Y MUJERES
        for(j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            A[i][j][3].notas = A[i][j][3].notas + A[i][j][2].notas;
            A[i][j][3].cont = A[i][j][3].cont + A[i][j][2].cont;
            A[i][j][3].contex = A[i][j][3].contex + A[i][j][2].contex;
        }
    }

    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            cantidadM = cantidadM + A[i][j][1].cont;
            califM = califM + A[i][j][1].notas;
        }
    }

    prom_m = califM / cantidadM; //PROMEDIO DE CALIFICACIONES DE LOS HOMBRES

    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            cantidadF = cantidadF + A[i][j][2].cont;
            califF = califF + A[i][j][2].notas;
        }
    }

    prom_f = califF / cantidadM; //PROMEDIO DE CALIFICACIONES MUJERES

    for(k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
               A[6][j][k].cont = A[6][j][k].cont + A[i][j][k].cont;
               A[6][j][k].contex = A[6][j][k].contex + A[i][j][k].cont;
               A[6][j][k].notas = A[6][j][k].notas + A[i][j][k].notas;
            }
        }
    }

    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        A[6][j][3].cont = A[6][j][1].cont + A[6][j][2].cont;
        A[6][j][3].cont = A[6][j][1].contex + A[6][j][2].contex;
        A[6][j][3].notas = A[6][j][1].notas + A[6][j][2].notas;
    }
    
    resmay = A[6][1][3].contex;
    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        if(A[6][j][3].contex > resmay) {
            resmay = A[6][j][3].contex;
            jex = j;
        }
    }

    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        for(k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            A[7][j][k].notas = A[6][j][k].notas / A[6][j][k].cont;
        }
    }

    resmen = A[7][1][3].notas;
    resmay = A[7][1][3].notas;
    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        if(A[7][j][3].notas > resmay) {
            resmay = A[7][j][3].notas;
            jmay = j;
        }
        else {
            if(A[7][j][3].notas < resmen) {
                resmen = A[7][j][3].notas;
                jmen = j;
            }
        }
    }

    etario(jmay, grupoed);
    printf("\nEl rango etario con mayor calificacion en promedio fue el comprendido entre: %s%s", grupoed, " años");
    etario(jmen, grupoed);
    printf("\nEl rango etario con menor calificacion en promedio fue el comprendido entre: %s%s", grupoed, " años");
    printf("\nEl promedio de calificaciones en femeninos fue: %f", prom_f);
    printf("\nEl promedio de calificaciones en masculinos fue: %f", prom_m);
    etario(jex, grupoed);
    printf("\nEl rango etario con mayor interes en rendir examenes internacionales es el comprendido entre: %s", grupoed, "años");

    fclose(entrada);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMja8.png)
there we can see that the values of i, j and k are out of the array defined range, so obviusly it breaks the code...

Just in case i will explain how the file was made, it was generated by another program that use rand function to generate random data about people in a certain range, also it has a print just to have control of the values that the structs are taking:
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct persona {
    int edad; //EDAD DE 12-65//
    int notas; //NOTAS DE 0-10//
    char sexo; //SEXO 1=MASCULINO Y 2=FEMENINO//
    char exi; //EXI 1=SI 2=NO
};

void generacion()
{
    FILE *entrada;
    entrada=fopen("datospersonas.txt","ab");
    if (entrada == NULL){
        exit(1);
    }
    fclose(entrada);
}

int main()
{
    int s;
    int exi;
    generacion();
    persona p;
    FILE* entrada;
    entrada=fopen("datospersonas.txt","ab");
    srand(time(NULL));

        for (size_t i=0;i<650; i++)
        {
            p.edad =(rand() %54)+12;
            p.notas =(rand() %10)+1;
            s=(rand() %2)+1;
            if(s == 1){
                p.sexo='M';
            }
            else{
                p.sexo='F';
            }
            exi=(rand() %2)+1;
            if(exi == 1){
                p.exi='S';
            }
            else{
                p.exi='N';
            }
            fwrite(&p, sizeof(struct persona),1,entrada);
            printf("edad: %d\n",p.edad);
            printf("nota: %d\n",p.notas);
            printf("sexo: %c\n",p.sexo);
            printf("esta interesado en rendir examenes internacionales: %c\n",p.exi);
        }
        fclose(entrada);
        return 0;
}
```

`

I have tried doing a file manually, like charging the data by myself to see if the file its not the problem.

Comment: Read this:  [**Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: Also, debugger...